# how to get Activity View inside that activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I want to show my next activity withing my previous activity layout "LinearLyout". But it is not working. Can any one help?

I put my last activity layout reference to a global class in an static variable. My code in next activity is as follow

> public onCreate(){
>
> View view = findViewById(R.layout.topstory_detail_layout);
> setContentView(view);
> // My code
>
> Global.mainActity.contentViewLayout.removeAllViews();
> Global.mainActity.contentViewLayout.addView(this.getWindow().getDecorView());

**Here is exception**

> 11-11 11:41:07.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(559): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
> 11-11 11:41:07.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(559): java.lang.RuntimeException: view com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44c3cc70 being added, but it already has a parent
> 11-11 11:41:07.460: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(559):     at android.view.View.assignParent(View.java:5721)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain it better what is global an activity?

btw if i understand you want do create an activity group that contains an activity 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html

and you can read what is here

http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg37528.html

Comment: Thanks. Yes I got it , using activitymange in group activity.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store anything context-related in global static variables, this leads to memory leaks.

Maybe you should just perform the start your second ativity with [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) flag. In this case, the new activity will substitute the first one.

Also you can call current activity's finish() just after the startActivity().

Finally, you might want to use the [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) to change Activity's view.